# Access to element in loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I wrote this script below to change all types of columns `nvarchar` to `varchar` and `nchar` to `char`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
INTO
    #Temp
FROM
    DATA.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
    TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('SCHEMA1', 'SCHEMA2')
    AND DATA_TYPE LIKE 'nvar%' 
    OR DATA_TYPE LIKE 'nch%'

SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
FROM #Temp

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Temp) > 0
BEGIN
    IF DATA_TYPE LIKE 'nvarchar'
        ALTER TABLE_NAME 
           ALTER COLUMN_NAME CAST (COLUMN_NAME AS varchar)
    ELSE IF DATA_TYPE LIKE 'nchar'
        ALTER TABLE_NAME 
            ALTER COLUMN_NAME CAST (COLUMN_NAME AS char)
    ELSE 
       DELETE #Temp 
END
```

My question is how can I access to each `element` in `Temp` because always I do it by `Foreach` and may be is not accessible in SQL Server this loop.

Not yet I running my script because I have a large number of tables and I want verify.

Someone please can tell me how I change my `loop while` to access on each element in `Temp`.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do this in the first place?!

Comment: you talking about what sorry ?

Comment: Changing nvarchars to varchars

Comment: Why do you want to convert all your columns from `NVARCHAR` to `VARCHAR`?

Comment: To gain more space in my database, because I don't have an efficient space.

Comment: This is a terrible way to reclaim space, and will potentially mean you lose data.

Comment: Does this work? Where is data_type being assigned a value? Its not in a select (where a 'case' clause would be used). If its a tsql variable (if something =something) it has to be assigned a value and declared. You probably need to do an exec statement and build the alter statement dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

See Microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql example B - while with a cursor.

Your alter table commands will not work - you will need to build the string and then use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql

Before doing either of these steps I would try to formulate a test case instead of altering your schema while you are developing this solution. Make sure you have a backup.

@DavidG - David is correct, you could end up losing data by doing this. Proceed with caution.